# Get запрос на сторонний URL в Express.js

Tags: node.js, express

Ситуация такая: нужно через экспресс обратиться к стороннему серверу, который возвращает json, эти данные обработать и вернуть клиенту на Vue.

Проблема заключается в том, что сервер работает на http протоколе и возникает CORS ошибка. Как быть?

Так же с экспресс я не слишком силен, поэтому пока не понимаю, как решить поставленную задачу без базы данных.

Comment: а как вам база данных поможет с CORS? :) https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html

Comment: Про базу данных упомянул к слову про то, что данные надо обрабатывать и возвращать. Хотя уже вроде разобрался с этим)